# How can you open an IE8 window with the nomerge option in javascript

Tags: javascript, session, internet-explorer-8, window.open

When using window.open(....) is there a way to use the -nomerge option.

I'd like to be able to check for the browser type, and open a new window with a new session. Is there a clean way to do that in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have javascript run executables from the operating system, so you can't specify the -nomerge flag like that.

also, it's now `-noframemerging` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330728(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: as far as I can tell, both -noframemerging and -nomerge work.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't get a new session in a new window in any browser. They will all use any existing session cookies even with a new window.